# ASP.NET Repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I'm not familiar with the asp.net repeater control. I have two columns in the repeater, quantity and sku. On button click, I want to loop through the rows in the repeater and pass in each quantity and sku into a method. How do you get this information in a repeater?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the method for the button click:

```
foreach(RepeaterItem item in repeaterControlID.Items)
{
    var quantity = item.FindControl("quantityControlID");
    var sku = item.FindControl("skuControlID");
}
```

Or something like that.  You could alternatively use the RepeaterItem's Controls property to look through them.

E: my interpretation of your question was: "On the postback caused by a button click, I want to loop through the items in the repeater and pass those values into a method."  This will not be applicable to populating the repeater *or* doing something in client-side javascript.

And of course, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx) is a great resource for learning how to use various classes, like the [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Client side or server side?  Assuming you mean server side, use the repeater's OnItemDataBound event.  That will fire once per row, with the data for the row included as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are displaying "quantity" and "sku" in your ItemTemplate.  If you're using the `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "quantity") %>` syntax, you can do something like this:

```
foreach(RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
         {        
            string quantity = ((DataBoundLiteralControl)item.Controls[0]).Text;
            string sku = ((DataBoundLiteralControl)item.Controls[1]).Text;

         }
```

It would help though if you could post your ItemTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to "type" your controls too to access its properties...

`foreach(RepeaterItem item in this.RptTest.Items){
    string DdlTestValue = ((DropDown)item.FindControl("DdlTest")).SelectedValue;
    string TxtTestValue = ((TextBox)item.FindControl("TxtTest")).Text;
}`